# Given a list of integers, find the list consisting of the product of all elements but the current index

Tags: python, precision, floating-accuracy

I am working with Python 3.8.

Consider a list of (strictly) positive integers, for example

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

My task is to calculate a new list such that its ith element is the product of all elements in L but the ith one. So, for L given, our result will be

```
R = [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
```

Obviously, I can do

```
R = [functool.reduce(operator.mul, [L[ix] for ix in range(len(L)) if ix != k]) for k in range(len(L))]
```

This, however, has **quadratic** time complexity.

Mathematically, it would be much more efficient to simply multiply all elements of L and then construct R with a comprehension by dividing this product by each element of L. This, of course, has a floating-point accuracy limitation and it does not work in my computer for large lists (len(L) around 10^4 with numbers between 1 and 1000).

Any ideas on doing this? Notice that should the second approach work, the time complexity is reduce to *linear*.

Comment: " it does not work in my computer for large lists" *How* does it not work? does it take a long time? do you get a memory error? If the latter, you can use a generator that yields one element at a time instead of storing the entire lists in memory

Comment: @DeepSpace: The sentence that says dividing the product by an element does not work says it has a floating-point accuracy limitation. That is telling you why it does not work and hence how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck because Python has *arbitrary precision* integers! So you can in fact just multiply them all together and then divide by the given integer:

```py
L = [1,2,3,4,5]

prod = 1
for el in L:
    prod *= el

R = [prod//el for el in L]
```

Note that integer division `//` is used. As all elements `el` are factors of `prod` by construction, this always results in exact division. Using just `/` would result in floating-point division, possibly introducing errors.

Comment: "Using just / would result in floating-point division, possibly introducing errors." Why? if we know that `b` is a factor of `a`, then `a/b` is an integer. There is no reason for `/` to introduce an error

Comment: Anyway, OP already mentioned that this approach does not work on his system for lists of a certain length

Comment: Thank you, I was using int(big_num/small_num)*small_num and this was not big_num (I don't know why but it just wasn't).

Comment: @DeepSpace No, this works. `a/b` can only give around 17 digits of accuracy, which is obviously not enough if the number has say 100 digits. Contrary, `a//b` gives all digits.

Comment: @WillM. Writing `int(big_num/small_num)*small_num` is equivalent to `int(float(big_num)/float(small_num))*small_num`, i.e. `/` comes with an implicit cast to `float`.

Comment: @jmd_dk Ok, but OP says the numbers are in the range 1 to 1000

Comment: @DeepSpace ... so the product of 10^4 numbers between 1 and 1000 cannot have more than 17 digits?

Comment: @jmd_dk so my problem was an internal issue with Python in which an implicit cast to flaot was done (I already knew Python can handle arbitrary arithmetic with numbers but I didn't know that a//b and int(a/b) were _that_ different).